# Get-ClusterGroup and foreach using imported SQL table

Tags: sql-server, powershell, foreach

I am looking at getting information from a number of servers i.e. clustername, nodename, and state.

I can get the correct ouput when I hardcode the names into a `foreach` loop like this:

```
$clusters = "Cluster1", "Cluster2"
foreach ($cluster in $clusters) {
    Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $cluster
}
```

but when I run this version that pulls the information from a SQL table its coming up with the below error.

```
$clusters = $SQLServer = "DatawarehouseServer" #use Server\Instance for named SQL instances!
$SQLDBName = "Datawarehouse"
$SqlQuery = "SELECT clusters FROM dbo.clusters"

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDBName;Integrated Security=True"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$SqlConnection.Close()

clear

$DataSet.Tables[0]

foreach ($cluster in $clusters) {
    Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $cluster
}
```

```
WARNING: If you are running Windows PowerShell remotely, note that some failover
clustering cmdlets do not work remotely.  When possible, run the cmdlet locally
and specify a remote computer as the target. To run the cmdlet remotely, try
using the Credential Security Service Provider (CredSSP). All additional errors
or warnings from this cmdlet might be caused by running it remotely.
Get-ClusterGroup : The cluster service is not running.  Make sure that the
service is running on all nodes in the  cluster. There are no more endpoints
available from the endpoint mapper
At line:26 char:2
+ {Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $cluster}
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (:) [Get-ClusterGroup], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ClusterEndpointNotRegistered,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.GetClusterGroupCommand.
```

I have now been trying this I seem to be getting  step closer or a step back depedant on how you look at it. It pulls the correct information out now but for only one cluster:

Thanks to the comments I have managed to get a step further or a step backwards with this:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=Datawarehouseserver;Database=Datawarehouse;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT clusters FROM dbo.clusters"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$clustername = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
$SqlConnection.Close()
#Write-Output "Cluster is " $dbname
clear
foreach ($cluster in $clustername) {
    Get-ClusterGroup -Cluster $cluster
}
```

Comment: `$clusters` is just a single string with the content "DatawarehouseServer", so the loop is trying to connect to a cluster with that name and then failing.  It looks like you need to loop through `$DataSet` but I don't work with SQL data often enough to be sure without testing and I don't have a suitable env in front of me.

Comment: Thanks I have managed to get a step further or a step backwards with this.

it wont let me add to this comment bit Ill try and edit the main post.

Comment: `foreach ($cluster in $DataSet.Tables[0].clusters)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the cluster names returned by your SQL query, but your variable `$cluster` is never assigned that list of names. Use this instead:

```
foreach ($cluster in $DataSet.Tables[0].clusters) {
  ...
}
```